# Using Shortcuts to fill a text box and send form on webpage

Tags: iphone, safari, siri, shortcuts-app

Is it possible to give my phone the command "Hey Siri, Car Tax, ABC1234" for it then to automatically:

1. open a web browser
2. navigate to the website https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk
3. locate the form box
4. input the spoken text string 'ABC1234'
5. Submit

Siri is capable of accepting "Text to Speech" inputs using the "Ask for Inputs" scripting function. But I'm not knowledgable enough to know how to ask it to navigate to a form box on a website - or if it's possible.

Using the following method I can ask "Hey Siri, Car Tax", it pauses and then asks me "Reg?" (short for registration number - a preset that I prescribed), I then say a sequence of letters and number (for example, ABC1234) and this voice string ('provided input') is them copied to the clipboard.  The browser opens, navigates to the website listed above, at which point I have to manually paste the voice string/provided input into the form and submit it. This is useful already, but I'd like to automate the final parts but this is where I am now stuck:

1. Scripting - 'Ask for' TEXT with REG?
2. Sharing - 'Copy' (magic variable) PROVIDED INPUT
3. Google Chrome - 'Open' URL

I believe step 4 may require JavaScript code to locate the text box ID, step 5 fills in the box with the 'provided input' and step 6 would click 'continue'.

Can someone please help me with these final 3 steps?

Thank you

Comment: Siri will execute any ShortCut if you make it available to it. Besides that - to post/fill into a properly marked up form on a webpage, you can just use _Get Contents of URL_ within ShortCuts. Change the method to _POST_ (it's going to submit the form when you run the shortcut), and set the request body to _Form_. Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Thanks, @slartibartfast.  Siri is executing what I have done so far perfectly, it's just that the instructions I've given it aren't perfect...yet.  You seem to be confident that what I want to do is achievable, which was to me until now, an unknown.   So, with your additional step which I've tried to do (I can't get it to work), I've also removed a now unnecessary step of 'copy to clipboard'. 
 The iCloud link to the shortcut so far is here - https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/4220ae7853754b71a088d47a758eaed7. Can you help me with the POST part?  Thank you

Comment: I did a quick look and it appears that there is a [javascript function which does the query and which one can probably use from ShortCuts](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/shortcuts/apdb71a01d93/ios). Another approach as mentioned is to identify  the 2 elements on the site to transmit a plate query and use that. Open the URL, get the element and post your progress so someone can look at it. Otherwise it might be helpfull to ask on StackOverflow for additional help - e.g. on how use Javascript to execute a query from the site.

Comment: @slartibartfast Are you now saying it's not possible to use the "Get Contents of URL/POST" method?  I've added the shortcut in my first reply - that shows my progress.  I've previously also tried the Javacript function that you've linked to, but I run into the same problem of not knowing how to use it.  Perhaps I'm not explaining myself clearly - I've explored the options that seem to be available and that seem to suggest they should work - it's at this point I'm seeking help to make them work.  I don't have the expertise to get past this point myself.

Comment: if you get the elements identified _Get Contents of URL_ should work. I glanced over the source code and the elements of the website you gave, and I haven’t found a quick method on the device I have access to and therefore the time to find the right element or capture the syntax of the query to offer a ready-made solution. I suggest you identify the element yourself and implement it in the short cut - I suggest trying it with a fixed string for a plate to debug, and then later add the more trivial part of supporting Siri.

Comment: @slartibartfast I'm making many assumptions here as a layman.  There is only one text box to fill in, so I assume that means there is only element to find.  That element has the ID "wizard_vehicle_enquiry_capture_vrn_vrn".  Using _Get Contents of URL_ Method _POST_ Request Body _Form_ I then use the ID above as the _Key_, Type _Text_ and as suggested a fixed string of _ABC1234_ for the Value.  It sadly doesn't work.